# Docker Swarm, Compose V3 and exposed IP address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

How can I define an IP for a server to work with in Swarm mode.
How to set the IP and PORT for accesing th service from outside?

Using docker 1.13.0 and docker-compose 1.10.0

regards

Answer (score 0):

The IP will be the IP of your swarm nodes. And the port will be the port you publish in your compose file. See [this documentation on publishing ports](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) but ignore the host ip part.

Comment: Many thanks @BMitch
Another question, how can I dynamically and externally expose a service?

The idea is not to have a specific port for each application
Is it necessary to use any tool that is not provided by docker swarm?
regards

Comment: I'd recommend a reverse proxy, like traefik, to access any service running over a single port rather than exposing a different port for each service. It lets you access them via different dns names or a url path.